# FATAL EXCEPTION - cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin

Tags: facebook, cordova

Im new to phonegap, android and facebook , and I wanted to add a login using facebook.

I did all the steps as per facebook's getting started guide for android,

got this error:

```
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin$AuthorizeListener.onComplete(ConnectPlugin.java:277)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.onSessionCallback(Facebook.java:345)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.access$11(Facebook.java:326)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.call(Facebook.java:304)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.facebook.Session$3$1.run(Session.java:1190)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-25 09:52:24.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any idea? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

In `ConnectPlugin.java`, replace:

```java
try {
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(this.fba.facebook.request("/me"));
    this.fba.userId = o.getString("id");
    this.fba.success(getResponse(), this.fba.callbackId);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

with the following code:

```java
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(fba.facebook.request("/me"));
            fba.userId = o.getString("id");
            fba.success(getResponse(), fba.callbackId);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
t.start();
```

Ref : [NetworkOnMainThreadException on Facebook Login with Phonegap 1.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757577/networkonmainthreadexception-on-facebook-login-with-phonegap-1-6-0)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I look into ConnectPlugin.java but the code is already there under : public void onComplete(Bundle values)

Comment: Same problem here. I think the problem is phonegap plugin is using so many deprecated facebook api.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out line 277 of `org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin.java`

```
//Log.d(TAG, values.toString());
```

It's only a log to the console